# LWC JavaScript way to copy List [List A, List B] Values to a single List

Tags: lightning-web-components, list, wrapper-class, js

I'm looking for a way to copy wrapper list of content values to a single list

Example:

```
LIST<wrapper> dataAandB= [LIST A,LIST B] => List A =[Object X :{Id,Name ... }] and List B =[Object Y :{Id,Name, ...}]

let xObjlist = [];

xObjlist=List A;
```

Is it possible to copy without using data.forEach() ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. You can use concat:

```
var output = listA.concat(listB);
```

Or you can flatten it:

```
var output = [listA,listB].flat();
```

Arrays in JS are very robust. You should take time to study their many features on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Comment: Awesome thank you @sfdxfox , I will definitely go through MDN thanks for your guidance.

Comment: also another way  `[...listA,...listB]`.